# Xcode + Swift: Showing view on top of another

Tags: ios, xcode, view, swift, segue

When my app performs a certain segue, I want the new view to be shown on top of the previous view, like a background. How do I do this?

If this is not possible, is there any way I could programmatically take a screenshot of the previous screen to use as a background for the new screen?

Answer (score 0):

There's a method on UIView, snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates: than will give you a composite view of the current screen. You could use that for your background.

You might look into custom view transitions to do what you're after though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a segue to a different view controller, why not just add the new view to the current controller, place it so that it appears above the first view and then set it as hidden.

When the user taps the action that would trigger the segue (a tableview cell for instance), then instead to triggering the segue, just mark the second view as visible and populate it's content with what you need to display.

With a clear background on the second view, it will overlay the original view.  Then you can just add some control to hide it once they're through.